# CakePHP and PHP file upload confusion

Tags: php, cakephp, upload

In CakePHP view, When I try this  code

```
    <?php echo $form->input('download_link', array('type'=>file)); ?>>
```

whose HTML output is

```
<input type="file" name="data[Publication][download_link]" value="" id="PublicationDownloadLink" />
```

is not working

but Plain HTML form in same view is working

```
<input type="file" name="download_link" class="engInput" />
```

Could somebody please explain why? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. But it's still not working. Please look at the question again, I've updated it.

Comment: what do you mean by 'not working'?  It is outputting html, as it is suppose to.

Comment: In controller, if I put this code

`code` $test=$_FILES["download_link"]["type"];
var_dump($test); `code`

CakePHP code returns null but Plain HTML returns file type.

Comment: Cake stores the POST values of a form in a data array for you, which can be accessed as `$this->data` or `$this->request->data`. Mixing and matching reserved PHP variables and Cake is probably not wise at this particular point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be:

```
input('download_link', array('type'=>'file'));
```

(Note the quotes around `file`)